# How to fix: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python, list, sorting

So I have this code and you take a questionnaire, it will give you a score out of 50. Results is the list that the data/results from the questionnaire is in, for each person it contains your name, score(s) if you took the questionnaire more than once inside a tuple. It should print the data in alphabetical according to your name and print from scores high - to low. I have tested this by just using a filled in list in another program, I insert this into my main code, where I use .dat files and I get the error which you see in the title. Here is the code:

```
results = []
High_Scores = []
for x in results:
    temp = []
    y = i[1].sort(reverse=True)
    for i in reversed(x):
        temp.append(x)
    test2.append(temp)

results.sort()
High_Scores.sort(reverse=True)
print(results)
print(High_Scores)
```

Here is the code that it worked in before i put it in my main code:

```
    test = [[ "jeff", [48, 38] ], ["ted", [17, 26, 10] ], ["lol", [19]], ["lovely", [2]]]
    test2 = []
    for x in test:
        temp = []
        y = x[1].sort(reverse=True)
        for x in reversed(x):
             temp.append(x)
         test2.append(temp)

    test.sort()
    test2.sort(reverse=True)
    print(test)
    print(test2)
```

I tried this:

```
    results = []
    High_Scores = []
    High_Scores = sorted(results, key = lambda tup: tup[1], reverse = True)
    print (High_Scores)
    for x in results:
        temp = []
        y = x.sort(reverse=True)
        for i in reversed(x):
            temp.append(i)
        High_Scores.append(temp)

    results.sort()
    High_Scores.sort(reverse=True)
    print(results)
    print(High_Scores)
```

and get this as an error:

```
  y = x.sort(reverse=True)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: I tried running your code and I got `NameError: name 'results' is not defined`. [mcve] please.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add that in :/

Comment: Which line is the error happening on? `results.sort` or `test2.sort`?

Comment: I have added it now.

Comment: i think it's this line ` y = i[1].sort(reverse=True)`. what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I tried running your code and I got `NameError: name 'test2' is not defined`. [mcve] please.

Comment: This is the error I get so I assume this y = x[1].sort(reverse=True)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sort'

Comment: Why are you using `i[1]` before you define `i` in the `for i in reversed(x)` loop?

Comment: I have replaced test2 with High_Scores for all now.

Comment: You didn't replace `test2` on the `test.append` line.

Comment: Why don't you just post the **real** code? Then we don't have to deal with all the changed names.

Comment: `results` in empty... that for loop won't even be entered

Comment: added in the test code where it worked.

Comment: Okay, that looks better. Additionally, I would avoid redefining `x` within the loop. Saying `for x in reversed(x)` may give you unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is that you are trying to access `i` before it is initialized. You also append `x` to temp when you probably want to append `i`. The line `y = x[1].sort(reverse=True)` will be wrong because `x[1]` will be an `int` which is cannot be sorted, that doesn't make any sense, but `y = x.sort(reverse=True)` will sort the inner lists, because each loop `x` equals an inner list. But since you are using tuples your code will need reworking to deal with tuples which I will explain

---

Since you have a list of tuples and the first value is a name you will need to separate the scores from the name, convert them to a list to sort them, attach the name back to the sorted scores, and then convert it back to a tuple which isn't really necessary but I will do it none the less

```
results = [('A',1,2),('B',3,4),('C',5,6)]
High_Scores = [tuple([i[0]]+sorted(list(i[1:]), reverse=True)) for i in results]
print High_Scores

[('A', 2, 1), ('B', 4, 3), ('C', 6, 5)]
```

All that does is sort the scores for each person. Here is the list comprehension in a more readable form

```
results = [('A',1,2),('B',3,4),('C',5,6)]
High_Scores = []
for i in results:
    tmp = sorted(list(i[1:]), reverse=True)
    tmp = [i[0]]+tmp
    High_Scores.append(tuple(tmp))
print High_Scores
```

Now if you want to sort by name also you can do

```
from operator import itemgetter
results = [('B',1,2),('C',3,4),('A',5,6)]
High_Scores = []

results = [list(i) for i in results]
High_Scores = sorted(results)
High_Scores = [[i[0]]+sorted(i[1:], reverse=True) for i in High_Scores]
print High_Scores

[['A', 6, 5], ['B', 2, 1], ['C', 4, 3]] #I didn't convert back to tuple
```

I'll explain the last one since it's the most in depth. The list comprehension restructures the results list of tuples to a list of lists. It takes each tuple and puts them through the `list()` function which converts tuples to lists. Next it sorts the results inner lists by their first value. Last is a list comprehension where it loops through each inner list and splits the scores from the name and sorts them in reverse order and then concatenates the name back to the scores. Add print statements after each line to see what it is happening if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think this explanation could be clarified by saying how this could give an AttributeError instead of a NameError or UnboundLocalError or something more intuitive

Comment: When there is something in the list I still get the same error but when i put results = [] at the top it will just get rid of everything that has been appended to the list and will print it empty

Comment: @EDoggyDog if you start with an empty list you will end with an empty list. If your list is of the form `[1,2,3,4,5]` then this solution will not work because then you will be trying to sort `int`s. Please add a sample results list that isn't empty.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the results list I have, because there are tuples in it I am getting this error for some unknown reason to my knowledge:     y = x.sort(reverse=True)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sort'

Comment: @EDoggyDog well the error speaks for itself. Tuples don't have a sort method but lists do

Comment: When the results list is printed it looks like this, the data in the tuple goes accordingly: Name, score1, score2, score3 and then more scores will be added if you take the test more times: [('Edog', 0, 0, 0), ('Edoggydog', 0, 0, 0)]

Comment: @EDoggyDog can you make a dict of lists instead? That would be the nice way of doing it.

Comment: I don't know how to use dictionaries, would one of you be able to show me how please or not?

Comment: @EDoggyDog no I don't have time to explain dictionaries to you but you can read all about them [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)! They are very useful and you need to know how to use them to be a successful python programmer. If you've ever used a map in C++ they are very similar

Comment: Thank you, this works but i don't really understand how, would you mind explaining it please?

Comment: @EDoggyDog I added a description that should help. If you don't understand list comprehensions then [here](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php) is the link that I used to learn them. try and make simple ones also. That helped me the most. Also don't forget to click the green check if this solved your problem

Comment: @EDoggyDog [Here](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) is another good list comprehension explanation